# How to realize a prompt dialog box when load a large file or other things using Qt?

Tags: qt

I need to load a large file to parse and draw with OpenGL.  The whole process is very time-consuming. So I want to realize a prompt dialog box before parse. But the code as following is not work.

```
void parseFile()
{
    QMessageBox* msgbox = new QMessageBox();
    msgbox->setModal(false);
    msgbox->setWindowTitle(tr("message box"));
    msgbox->setText("Please wait patiently......")
    msgbox->show();

    /* parse file and draw */
    ......
}
```

But it shows like also be frozen:
[image]

How to realize it?

Comment: What about calling `QTimer::singleShot(1000, msgbox, SLOT(show()));` instead of `msgbox->show()`?

Comment: @vahancho That will not work if the thread is blocked by some heavy work. All signals and slots depend on event loop to be available and unblocked.

Comment: Check out https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprogressdialog.html , pay attention to what is said in its documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`show()` does not actually show the content of the dialog. It only tells the event loop to show the dialog ASAP. But since you call more code after immediately after `show()`, the evnt loop does not have a chance to do its work.

The easiest way to solve this is to call `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` after `msgbox->show()`. This will force the event loop to do the work immediately.

If this does not work then try this parameter `QCoreApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::WaitForMoreEvents)`

Another option would be to move the heavy calculation to a function and than show the dialog and then schedule the calculation using a timer.

```
...
msgbox->show();
QTimer::singleShot(0, &doHeavyWork);
```

This would first handle all events related to showing the dialog and only after that it will start the heavy work (i.e. parsing the file).